# merge multiple pdfs in order

Tags: java, pdf, itext

hey guys sorry for long post and bad language and if there is unnecessary details

i created multiple 1page pdfs from one pdf template using excel document

i have now 

something like this 

tempfile0.pdf

tempfile1.pdf

tempfile2.pdf

...

im trying to merge all files in one single pdf using itext5

but it semmes that the pages in the resulted pdf are not in the order i wanted
per exemple 

tempfile0.pdf in the first page

tempfile1. int the 2000 page

here is the code im using. 

the procedure im using is:

1 filling a from from a hashmap

2 saving the filled form as one pdf

3 merging all the files in one single pdf

```
public void fillPdfitext(int debut,int fin) throws IOException, DocumentException {


    for (int i =debut; i < fin; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> currentData = dataextracted[i];
        // textArea.appendText("\n"+pdfoutputname +" en cours de preparation\n ");
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.sourcePdfTemplateFile.toURI().getPath());
        String outputfolder = this.destinationOutputFolder.toURI().getPath();
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outputfolder+"\\"+"tempcontrat"+debut+"-" +i+ "_.pdf"));
        // get the document catalog
        AcroFields acroForm = stamper.getAcroFields();
        // as there might not be an AcroForm entry a null check is necessary
        if (acroForm != null) {
            for (String key : currentData.keySet()) {
                try {

                    String fieldvalue=currentData.get(key);
                    if (key=="ADRESSE1"){
                        fieldvalue = currentData.get("ADRESSE1")+" "+currentData.get("ADRESSE2") ;
                        acroForm.setField("ADRESSE", fieldvalue);
                    }
                    if (key == "IMEI"){

                        acroForm.setField("NUM_SERIE_PACK", fieldvalue);

                    }
                    acroForm.setField(key, fieldvalue);
                    // textArea.appendText(key + ": "+fieldvalue+"\t\t");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
        }
        stamper.close();
    }

}
```

this is the code for merging

```
 public void Merge() throws IOException, DocumentException
{
     File[] documentPaths = Main.objetapp.destinationOutputFolder.listFiles((dir, name) -> name.matches( "tempcontrat.*\\.pdf" ));
    Arrays.sort(documentPaths, NameFileComparator.NAME_INSENSITIVE_COMPARATOR);

    byte[] mergedDocument;

    try (ByteArrayOutputStream memoryStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
    {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfSmartCopy pdfSmartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, memoryStream);
        document.open();

        for (File docPath : documentPaths)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(docPath.toURI().getPath());
            try
            {
                reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();

                    PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfSmartCopy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
                    pdfSmartCopy.addPage(pdfImportedPage);

            }
            finally
            {
                pdfSmartCopy.freeReader(reader);
                reader.close();
            }
        }

        document.close();
        mergedDocument = memoryStream.toByteArray();
    }



    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(this.destinationOutputFolder.toURI().getPath()+"\\"+
            this.sourceDataFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "")+".pdf");
    try {
        stream.write(mergedDocument);
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }

    documentPaths=null;
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    r.gc();
}
```

my question is how to keep the order of the files the same in the resulting pdf

Comment: I have noticed that you use `==` for comparison of strings. It is wrong, you should use `equals` method on a string object instead.

Comment: yes thank you, i didnt pay attention for that @menteith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of naming of files. Your code
`new FileOutputStream(outputfolder + "\\" + "tempcontrat" + debut + "-" + i + "_.pdf")`
will produce:

- *tempcontrat0-0_.pdf*
- *tempcontrat0-1_.pdf*
- ...
- *tempcontrat0-10_.pdf*
- *tempcontrat0-11_.pdf*
- ...
- *tempcontrat0-1000_.pdf*

Where *tempcontrat0-1000_.pdf* will be placed before *tempcontrat0-11_.pdf*, because you are sorting it alphabetically before merge.

It will be better to left pad file number with `0` character using [leftPad()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad(java.lang.String,%20int)) method of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils` or `java.text.DecimalFormat` and have it like this *tempcontrat0-000000.pdf*, *tempcontrat0-000001.pdf*, ... *tempcontrat0-9999999.pdf*.

---

And you can also do it much simpler and skip writing into file and then reading from file steps and merge documents right after the form fill and it will be faster. But it depends how many and how big documents you are merging and how much memory do you have.

So you can save the filled document into `ByteArrayOutputStream` and after `stamper.close()` create new `PdfReader` for bytes from that stream and call `pdfSmartCopy.getImportedPage()` for that reader. In short cut it can look like:

```
// initialize

PdfSmartCopy pdfSmartCopy = new PdfSmartCopy(document, memoryStream);
for (int i = debut; i < fin; i++) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // fill in the form here

    stamper.close();    
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(out.toByteArray());
    reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
    PdfImportedPage pdfImportedPage = pdfSmartCopy.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    pdfSmartCopy.addPage(pdfImportedPage);

    // other actions ...
}
```

Comment: thank you so much thats exactly what i needed 
god bless you and your family